# Can the keys of a dictionary be used as the assigned-to variables in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I want to iterate over several lists simultaneously in a for loop.  These lists come from a dictionary, and I would like to use the dictionary keys as the names of the variables in the for loop.

I'd like to be able to do this

```
import itertools

x = {"name" : ["John", "Ava"], "age" : [36, 25]}
iterator = itertools.product(*list(x.values()))

for list(x.values()) in iterator:
   print(f"name - {name}, age - {age}")
```

And have it act like this

```
for name, age in iterator:
   print(f"name - {name}, age - {age}")
```

Resulting in this

```
name - John, age - 36
name - John, age - 25
name - Ava, age - 36
name - Ava, age - 25
```

Basically I don't want to manually write `name, age` because in my actual script there's like 20 variables and adding more is a possibility

I've tried the obvious *list(x.keys()) and some string manipulation followed by eval but neither seemed like they would return what I needed.  Anything that does what I need is fine, security of eval is not a concern.  If this is actually impossible I'd like to understand why, because it seems like it should be doable.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. A `for` loop is a form of assignment statement, which requires the names to be explicitly bound if you want to use them in the body of the loop.

Comment: `for x in iterator: print("name - {}, age - {}".format(*x))`

Comment: @chepner I can see why this would be the case, but I was thinking there's no reason is must be the case.  Not like C where variable names have to be sorted at compile.  Executing arbitrary code with `exec` is possible after all.

Comment: @Manuel sadly this doesn't solve the problem as the variables still aren't bound to properly named variables, but perhaps useful to someone else.

Comment: Without `exec`, the assignment simply saves references to values in an otherwise anonymous list. The code between `for` and `in` needs to be a valid lvalue. Something like `[name, age]` is fine; a function call like `list(...)` is not. With `exec`, you can dynamically construct code that replaces `list(...)` with the desired list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general taking a string and turning that into a variable is not a simple task (nor good programming). In general, variables are not meant to encompass the values they point to, they are simply place holders and should really be treated as such. They can be re-assigned, re-named, re-used, and we shouldn't care.  There are ways to do what you are suggesting, for example you could ask the namespace directly and create a variable,

```
globals()['x'] = 7 #Assigns the namespace the variable called x with a value of 7. 
print(x)
```

Don't do that though. The better way to approach your problem is probably to refactor your dataset so that it produces the keys alongside the data you want:

```
x           = {"name" : ["John", "Ava"], "age" : [36, 25]}
x_with_keys = [dict(zip(x.keys(),values)) for values in zip(*x.values())]

for d in x_with_keys:
    print(f"name - {d['name']}, age - {d['age']}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is  this what you want? Adding more key:list pairs into the dictionary will print all keys automatically

```
x = {"name" : ["John", "Ava"], "age" : [36, 25],'state':['NY','CA']}
for v in zip(*x.values()):
    print(', '.join([f'{k} - {v[i]}' for i,k in enumerate(x)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `format()` function takes `kwargs`!

You can use the `dict.keys()` function to get the names for the items in the iterator's tuples, then create a new dictionary using the names, and finally unpack the dict to pass it as kwargs to the format function.

```
x = {"name" : ["John", "Ava"], "age" : [36, 25]}
iterator = itertools.product(*list(x.values()))

dkeys = x.keys()

for vals in iterator:
    vals_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(dkeys, vals)}
    print("name: {name}; age: {age}".format(**vals_dict))
```

This gives the output

```
name: John; age: 36
name: John; age: 25
name: Ava; age: 36
name: Ava; age: 25
```